# If $I$ is an invertible ideal, then there is $\alpha$ with $N(\alpha I^{-1})$ coprime with $N(I)$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, dedekind-domain

> Let $\mathcal{O}$ be an order inside a quadratic number field (not necessarily maximal). I want to show that if $I$ is an invertible $\mathcal{O}$-ideal, then there is $\alpha \in I$ such that $N(\alpha I^{-1})$ is comprime with $N(I)$.

I know how to prove it in the case $\mathcal{O}$ is Dedekind. But, in general, it’s not necessarily true that every prime ideal is invertible, so $I$ might not factor into prime ideals. I tried arguing like this: let $P_1,…,P_n$ be the prime ideals that lie above the prime numbers that divide $N(I)$. Then, I want to show that there is $\alpha$ such that $\alpha \notin P_i I$ for every $i$. In other words, I want to show that it is not true that
$$I=\bigcup P_i I.$$
I feel like I somehow need to use the invertibility of $I$ and prime avoidance to arrive to a contradiction. But I haven’t been able to do it.

This problem comes from a more general statement where $\mathcal{O}$ is an order inside a quaternion algebra, and $I$ is an invertible fractional right $\mathcal{O}$-ideal. The hint says to look for $\alpha$ such that $I^{-1}\alpha \subseteq \mathcal{O}$ and then look locally. But I haven’t found that useful.

Do you have any suggestions on how to proceed, or an other idea for a proof?

Thanks!

Comment: Ah right I was confused. See my 3rd attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathfrak{p}_1,\ldots,\mathfrak{p}_N$ be the primes above $(N(I))$.

Find $r$ such that for each $n$ $$\exists \beta_n\in\mathcal{O},\qquad \beta_n \in (I,\mathfrak{p}_n^r),\not \in (I\mathfrak{p}_n,\mathfrak{p}_n^r)$$

The $(I\mathfrak{p}_n,\mathfrak{p}_n^r)$ being pairwise comaximal we can find $\alpha\in\mathcal{O}$ such that for each $n$ $$\alpha =\beta_n\bmod(I\mathfrak{p}_n,\mathfrak{p}_n^r)$$
We get that $(\alpha)=IJ$ where $J$ is coprime with all the $\mathfrak{p}_n$ which means that $\gcd(N(J),N(I))=1$.

Comment: But, it’s not necessarily true that every prime above I is invertible, right? Take the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$. Then (2) is invertible, but the prime ideal $(2, 1+\sqrt{-3})$ above (2) is not invertible.

Comment: How do I guarantee $\alpha\in I$? I know $\alpha \in (I,\mathfrak{p}_i^r)$ for all $i$, so I guess you can make $r$ big enough so that the product of of these prime powers is inside I, right? 
Also, was the invertibility of $I$ needed anywhere? 
Thank you so much!

Comment: Not sure why I removed the $I\subset \prod_{n=1}^N\mathfrak{p}_n^r$ condition. 

The invertibility is needed only at the last line I'd say.  $J=(\alpha)I^{-1}$ is an ideal of $\mathcal{O}$ so we can say that it is $(1)$ modulo $N(I)$ because it is not contained in any prime containing $N(I)$.

Comment: $\alpha$ vanishes in each $\mathfrak{p}_n$-primary part of $\mathcal{O}/I$ but it is not obvious how to make it rigorous and elementary