# Is the norm of a non-invertible ideal the gcd of the norm of its elements?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

Let $K$ be an imaginary quadratic number field and $\mathcal{O}$ a (possibly non-maximal) order inside $K$. Consider $I$ to be an $\mathcal{O}$-ideal. The norm $N(I)$ is given by the index $[\mathcal{O}:I]$. I'm reading a paper that states without proof that $$N(I)=\gcd(\{N(\alpha) \mid \alpha \in I\})$$
I've been trying to prove this statement.
It's clear that $N(I) \mid \gcd(\{N(\alpha) \mid \alpha \in I\})$. Also, $N(I)\in I$, so $\gcd(\{N(\alpha) \mid \alpha \in I\}) \mid N(I)^2$. And this is where I get stuck.

So, I started to wonder if this is actually true even for non-invertible ideals. For example, consider $\mathcal{O}=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ and the singular prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}=(2,1+\sqrt{-3})$ with norm 2. With the aid of a computer algebra system, I computed an expression for the norm of a generic element in $\mathfrak{p}$ and it's always divisible by 4. So, $\gcd(\{N(\alpha) \mid \alpha \in \mathfrak{p}\})=4$, while $N(\mathfrak{p})=2$. Hence, the equality cannot be true for every $\mathcal{O}$-ideal.

My question is, do you know if this equality is true in the case of invertible ideals? If so, could you point me to a proof or a reference?

Thanks!

Comment: Didn't we settle this out in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4403294/276986 when $I$ is invertible? You are asking if it stays true when $I$ is not invertible, trying $(2,2i)$ in $\Bbb{Z}[2i]$ it seems that no

Comment: Ohhh. Funny enough, these two questions came from different problems I was working on. I didn't realize that that same $\alpha$ works as an example of an element with $N(\alpha)=N(I)k$ with $\gcd(k,N(I))=1$, proving the equality above. Brilliant! Thanks!